# Hadoop on local machine - Error occurred during initialization of VM, Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: hadoop, linux-mint

I'm trying to run [Wikipedia Miner's CSV extraction](http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Extracting%20CSV%20Summaries) on a wikipedia dump. I set up Hadoop 1.0.4 in single-node cluster configuration on a virtualized Mint 14 32-bit OS, using the instructions [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

The `hadoop*examples*.jar` works fine, but when I try to run the CSV extraction from Wikipedia Miner, I get a `Could not reserve enough space for object heap` error.

I'm not sure what information would be useful to provide.

I allocated 4 cores (actually 2 hyperthreaded) to Mint and 4GB of RAM, 2GB of swap space and more than enough HD space. I'm using VirtualBox 4.2.8 to run Mint as a guest on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.

I tried setting

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx####m</value>
</property>
```

in `mapred-site.xml` where values of 512, 768, 1024, 1536, 2048 were tried for `####`.

I also tried commenting out the above property and using `-Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx####m` inline when running the task.

Allocating more RAM to Mint wouldn't help, as it is 32 bit.

Nothing is working. Please help :'(.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?